# ValueError: No variables to optimize

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, gradient-descent

I'm trying to calculate `l2_loss` between two images and get `gradient` for them. A snippet of my code is given here:

```
with tf.name_scope("train"):

    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None, None, None], name='X')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, None, None, None], name='y')
    Z = tf.nn.l2_loss(X - y, name="loss")
    step_loss = tf.reduce_mean(Z)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(step_loss)

init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init.run()
    content = tf.gfile.FastGFile('cat.0.jpg', 'rb').read()
    noise = tf.gfile.FastGFile('color_img.jpg', 'rb').read()
    loss_append = []
    for epoch in range(10):
        for layer in layers:
            c = sess.run(layer, feed_dict={input_img: content})
            n = sess.run(layer, feed_dict={input_img: noise})
            sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: c, y: n})
```

But it gives the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/noise_image.py",     line 68, in <module>
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(lossss)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training /optimizer.py", line 315, in minimize
    grad_loss=grad_loss)
   File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training   /optimizer.py", line 380, in compute_gradients
    raise ValueError("No variables to optimize.")
ValueError: No variables to optimize.
```

How to get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The graph which you have constructed consists of no variable node. You are also trying to minimise the loss function without any variables.

**Minimisation** refers to finding a set of values for the variables of a mathematical function (cost function) which when substituted in the function gives the minimum possible value (At least local minimum as we usually deal with non-convex functions).

So, when you run the code, the compiler is complaining that there is no variable in your cost function.
Just as a clarification, `placeholder` refers to objects which are used to feed values to various inputs to your graph during runtime.

To solve the problem, you have to think again about the graph you are trying to construct. You have to define variables something like this: (Ignoring non-related part of code with this problem)

```
with tf.name_scope("train"):
    X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 224, 224, 3], name='X')
    y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [1, 224, 224, 3], name='y') 

    X_var = tf.get_variable('X_var', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal((1, 224, 224, 3)))
    y_var = tf.get_variable('y_var', dtype = tf.float32, initializer = tf.random_normal((1, 224, 224, 3)))
    Z = tf.nn.l2_loss((X_var - X) ** 2 + (y_var - y) ** 2, name="loss")

    step_loss = tf.reduce_mean(Z)
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer()
    training_op = optimizer.minimize(step_loss)

...
with tf.Session() as sess:
    ....
    sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={X: c, y: n})
```

Answer (score 1):

`X` and `y` have values fed in from `feed_dict`, and `Z` is a function of these, so TensorFlow can't train them.

Instead of setting `X` to be a placeholder, assign it to its tensor value (`layer`). Do the same for `y`.

Your final code should look something like:

```
for epoch in range(10):
    sess.run(training_op, feed_dict={input_image_content: content, input_image_noise: noise})
```

Comment: `layer` is the output obtained by restoring a particular layer from a model file here. How can I evaluate the tensor value of `layer` and feed it to `X` and `y` without using `placeholder` ?

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. I intended to give upvote but mistakenly pushed the wrong button and now it's locked.